# ¿Cómo buscar la primera posición de aparición de un digito en una lista?

Tags: python

```
    def buscar_elementov3(entrada:list,buscado:int)->int:
        cadena_de_lista="".join([str(variable) for variable in entrada])
        longitud=len(cadena_de_lista)
        buscadostr=str(buscado)
        if buscado in entrada:
            for variable in range(0,longitud):            
                if cadena_de_lista[variable]==buscadostr:
                    posicion=variable
       elif buscado not in entrada:
             posicion=-1
       return posicion
```

Este es mi código, me calcula correctamente la ubicación de un número entrado por parámetro en una lista entrada por parámetro. El problema es que si la lista tiene varias veces el mismo número, arroja la posición de la última vez que aparece, y necesito que arroje la posición de la primera aparición.

Además el problema indica que la solución no debe contener ninguna función tal como find, index o cualquier otra. El programa debe funcionar sólo con los ciclos while y for.

Comment: Por favor agrega tu código como texto y no como imagen, lee [ask]

Comment: Debe encontrar el índice de un número. Si el número está en la lista debe retornar el índice de este número, si el número no está en la lista debe retornar - 1

Comment: Creo que ya la edité correctamente, perdón de la demora, soy nuevo en esto.

Answer (score 2):

Para que solo retorne el índice del primer elemento encontrado debes romper el ciclo cuando se encuentre con `break` o con un `return`, de lo contrario iterará sobre toda la lista y posición será la del último item que cumpla con la condición de igualdad.

No obstante, tu aproximación falla en el caso de tener una lista con números de más de un dígito:

> ```
> >>> buscar_elementov3([1, 23, 521], 23)
> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'posicion' referenced before assignment
> ```

Esto pasa porque `if cadena_de_lista[variable]==buscadostr:` nunca es cierta, `cadena_de_lista[variable]` es un solo carácter mientras que `buscadostr` tendrá más de uno. Realmente te estás complicando mucho, basta con un solo ciclo y el condicional, la conversión a `str` de la lista no es necesaria:

```
def buscar_elemento(entrada: list, buscado: int) -> int:
    for índice in range(len(entrada)):
        if buscado == entrada[índice]:
            return índice
    return -1
```

o si puedes usar `enumerate`, es más eficiente y pitónico que usar `range` + `len` e indizado:

```
def buscar_elemento(entrada: list, buscado: int) -> int:
    for índice, item in enumerate(entrada):
        if buscado == item:
            return índice
    return -1
```

Si quieres usar un solo estamento `return` puedes hacer:

```
def buscar_elemento(entrada: list, buscado: int) -> int:
    posición = -1
    for índice, item in enumerate(entrada):
        if buscado == item:
            posición = índice
            break
    return posición
```

> ```
> >>> buscar_elemento([1, 13, 25, 13], 13)
> 1
> >>> buscar_elemento([1, 13, 25, 13], 3)
> -1
> >>> buscar_elemento([1, 13, 25, 13], 25)
> 2
> ```

Comment: Wow, si la verdad me estaba complicando bastante, era mucho más sencillo de lo que imaginaba, muchas gracias por tu ayuda y tu punto de vista :)